# Gmail for one email address, inbox for the other

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I have 2 google email accounts, one personal and one for work. I want to use my personal email account on Inbox and my work email on Gmail. I want it so that when I receive emails I can see each icon so that at a glance I know if the email is personal or for work. How can I set this up?